# Check if a String startsWith() and isn't equal to another String

Tags: javascript, string, startswith

I wanna know if a String (for example: "Hello World!") starts with "Hello" and isn't equal to "Hello Wourld" but I don't know how to make it. I tried:
`if(String.startsWith("Hello") && (String !== "Hello Wourld")) {
    // Do something 
}`
But it doesn't work. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/toc02re1/ works for me

Comment: Works on browser as well

Comment: May be your browser doesn't have the 'startsWith' function (IE 11 doesn't).

Comment: `String` is a reserved native constructor for strings,.  try and avoid creating a var named this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to test for "starts with" in any version of javascript.

```
var value = 'Hello There';

if (/^Hello/.test(value) && value !== 'Hello World') {
  console.log('yes it is!')
}
```